# Shorter way to use Array.Copy when passing the result?

Tags: c#

I have copy part of an array then pass it into a constructor frequently.

Is there a more concise (and still performant) way to do this? Pasting these 3 lines of code everywhere (with a different MessageClass) feels not-very-DRY, but I can't figure out how to refactor it.

```
// Example set-up
byte[] packetBody = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06 };

// Different Message class each time I do this
// AuthenticationMessage.Length is a const ushort
var messageData = new byte[AuthenticationMessage.Length];
Array.Copy(packetBody, 0, messageData, 0, AuthenticationMessage.Length);
var message = new AuthenticationMessage(messageData);
```

edit -- if it helps here is the base class:

```
using System; 

abstract public class GameMessage {      

    public enum MessageTypes : ushort {
        POSITION = 1,
        AUTHENTICATION = 2,                
        REQUEST = 3
    };        

    public const ushort HeaderLength = 2;                                     
    public ushort Length { get; }
    public MessageTypes Type { get; }
    public byte[] Data { get; }

    protected GameMessage(ushort length, MessageTypes type, byte[] data = null) {
        Length = length;
        Type = type;
        Data = new byte[length];                       

        // Initialize if we were passed raw data
        if (data != null) {       
            Array.Copy(data, 0, Data, 0, length);
        }     
    }     

    public byte[] Header () {
        return F8Tools.FixEndian (BitConverter.GetBytes ((ushort)Type));
    }

    public byte[] Body () {
        var body = new byte[BodyLength()];
        Array.Copy(Data, HeaderLength, body, 0, BodyLength());
        return body;
    }     

    public ushort BodyLength () {
        return (ushort)(Length - HeaderLength);
    }         
}
```

And one of the child classes:

```
using System;

public class AuthenticationMessage : GameMessage {

    // Required for base class initialization
    public const ushort Length_ = 39;
    private const MessageTypes type = MessageTypes.AUTHENTICATION;
    public AuthenticationMessage (byte[] data) : base (Length_, type, data) {}
    // End required for base class initialization

    public enum Indices {
        ACCOUNT_ID_INDEX = 2,
        ACCOUNT_ID_LENGTH = 4,
        STATUS_INDEX = 6,
        STATUS_LENGTH = 1,
        HASH_INDEX = 7,
        HASH_LENGTH = 32,
    };

    public enum AuthStatuses : byte {
        REQUEST = 1,
        SUCCESS = 2,
        FAILURE = 3
    }

    public AuthStatuses AuthStatus () {
        return (AuthStatuses) Data[(int)Indices.STATUS_INDEX];
    }

    public AuthenticationMessage (int accountId, byte[] tokenHash) : base (Length_, type) {
        // Header
        Array.Copy(Header(), 0, Data, 0, HeaderLength);
        // Account ID
        byte[] idBytes = F8Tools.FixEndian (BitConverter.GetBytes(accountId));
        Array.Copy(idBytes, 0, Data, (int)Indices.ACCOUNT_ID_INDEX, (int)Indices.ACCOUNT_ID_LENGTH);
        // AuthStatus
        Data[(int)Indices.STATUS_INDEX] = (byte)AuthStatuses.REQUEST;
        // Token Hash
        Array.Copy(tokenHash, 0, Data, (int)Indices.HASH_INDEX, (int)Indices.HASH_LENGTH); // Hash char Length_ is 32
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you only taking the first `n` number of items in all of your use cases? Could potentially do `var messageData = packetBody.Take(MessageClass.Length).ToArray();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing this to solve my problem:

```
public static byte[] ArrayCopy(byte[] source, int length, int start = 0) {
    var dest = new byte[length];                                          
    Array.Copy(source, start, dest, 0, length);                           
    return dest;                                                          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a static method on MessageClass that takes a byte[] parameter and returns a new MessageClass:

```
public static MessageClass NewMessageClass(byte[] packetBody)
{
    var messageData = new byte[Length];
    Array.Copy(packetBody, 0, messageData, 0, Length);
    return new MessageClass(messageData);
}
```

That way the logic is defined in one spot and you can call it from anywhere that has access to MessageClass.

Comment: The only problem with this is that I have a ton of different MessageClasses, so it would still be in many different places.  Is it possible to add another method in Array like Array.CopyReturn that would return a new Array instead of copying it into an existing Array?

Comment: Put it in an abstract class the other MessageClasses inherit from

Comment: (edited above, I hit enter on accident before completing my comment).  I don't think it would be possible to return a MessageClass from BaseMessageClass would it?

Comment: It would help to know more about your structure.  Can you post some examples of what your different classes look like in your OP?

Comment: I updated the OP.  I also figured out a way to do what I'm looking for with a static method, but I'm still curious about what you are suggesting, because it would be pretty simple if I can spawn child classes from the base class.